# XSL to XHTML Strict with DOCTYPE - META tag validation issue

Tags: html, xslt, xhtml

**XSL Sample**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  version="1.0"
  >
    <xsl:output method="html"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/Report">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
            <head>
```

**The problem:** I need to define the DOC TYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

in the XSL but it's not letting me put it in there, says invalid style sheet.

I tried:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN&quot; &quot;DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd&quot;&gt;</xsl:text>
```

but is it the proper way to do this? Online Validators don't even see that line which when rendered by html is supposed to be valid.

1. What's the proper way of adding DOCTYPE?
2. should my `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` still be transform there or?

I have an XML data file with XSL style sheet that i transform into an html. I want to add the above to make it XHTML Strict Compliant. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Strict DTD XHTML Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
Please Choose a Day:
            <br />
            <br />
            <select name="day">
                <option selected="selected">Monday</option>
                <option>Tuesday</option>
                <option>Wednesday</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Generated XHTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>OWASP ZAP Vulnerability Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Issues** Using: https://validator.w3.org/

- The issue seems to be caused by the `META` tag in the `head` element but i don't understand why.

So how do i stop my XSL from adding the META tag?

**SOLUTION**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  version="1.0"
  >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/Report">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
</xsl:text>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
            <head>
```

Change the `xsl:output method` from html to xml. But back to the other question, is there a better way to declare `DOCTYPE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attributes of `xsl:output`, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output, i.e.`doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"`, then the XSLT processor on serializing adds the `DOCTYPE`.